# Передвижение машины на 10 метров

Tags: java

Дан метод move() - изначально он пуст, я его сам заполняю, который перемещает автомобиль на 1 метр вперед или назад. При перемещении вперед он вернет значение true, а при движении назад false. Автомобиль сам решает куда он движется в при вызове метода move. Задача - переместить автомобиль на 10 метров вперед от начальной позиции автомобиля. Метод move(), согласно заданию, трогать нельзя, можно только его вызывать и пользоваться результатом выполнения. Наброски:

```
package pckgCar;

public class Car {
    public static int mCar = 0;     //пер. для генерации 0 или 1
    public static int mCarLen = 0;  //пер. для подсчета метров

    public static boolean A;        //пер. для возврата true||false в методе

    public static void main(String[] args) {    //главная ф-ция
        move();                                 //вызываем move()
    }
    public static boolean move(){               //возвращает true||false

        moving();                               //вызов метода moving();
        if(mCarLen==10){                        //если набралось 10 метров, то
            A = true;                           //приехали
            System.out.println("Приехали.");
        }
        return A;                               //возврат значения
    }
    public static void moving(){                //генерация 0 или 1, для вызова в мув, мув же не трогаем
        do                                      //делаем:
        {
        mCar = (int) (mCar + (Math.random() * ((-1 - 0)+1)));   //генерацию 0 или 1
        if(mCar==1){                                            //если 1, то
            mCarLen++;                                          //увеличичваем счетчик метров на 1, 

        } 
    }while(mCarLen < 11);                                       //пока не наберем 10
    }
}
```

Comment: А вопрос в чем? или нужно придумать вопрос? Но moving странный.

Comment: @KoVadim ну оно не работает, не заходит даже в if, где вывод

Comment: `(Math.random() * ((-1 - 0)+1))` здесь будет 0 всегда. Скобки более аккуратно поставьте.

Comment: @KoVadim та там минус лишний я ставил, проверял, у меня написано ...((1 - 0)+1))), генерирует оно правильно - либо 0, либо 1, проблема где-то в циклах, может?

Comment: Напишите, пожалуйста, как код вызывается/тестируется и что именно происходит не так, как ожидалось. Лучше всего создать [МСВП](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Фраза "метод `move`, согласно заданию, трогать нельзя"  противоречит фразе "Дан метод `move` - изначально он пуст, я его сам заполняю". Определитесь какой код таки можно изменять, а какой - нет. Реализация метода `moving`, который вызывается в методе `move`, опять-таки противоречит сути метода `move`, который, как вы сами пишете, "перемещает автомобиль на 1 метр вперед или назад".